# References are printed with spaces between them?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, urls

Is it possible to better format this so that I can remove the huge spaces between words?

Code used:

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}  
\bibliography{library}
```

Code in `.bib` library:

```
@misc{marsrover,
author = {Greicius, Tony},
booktitle = {NASA},
file = {:Users/user/Library/Application Support/Zotero/Profiles/zotero/storage/index.html:html},
howpublished = {http://www.nasa.gov/mission\_pages/msl/index.html},
title = {{\{NASA\} - Mars Science Laboratory}},
url = {http://www.nasa.gov/mission\_pages/msl/index.html}
}
```

[image]

---

Is this due to 'justify' style of the document ? Maybe I can prevent justifying the bibliography ? My document starts like this :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=3.81cm,tmargin=2.54cm,rmargin=2.54cm,bmargin=2.52cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.5}
```

*EDIT*

I can confirm that it's due to 'justify' .. I added `\raggedright` just before the bibliography and the text flushes to the left now.

However I would like to keep it justified but without the spacing ... Editing the margins is not efficient, anyone got an idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: How are you inserting the url address?

Comment: Load the `url` package in your document's preamble.

Comment: @Sigur What do you mean ?

Comment: @Mico How exactly ?

Comment: @NLed, paste here the item from your `bib` file which contain that reference.

Comment: @Sigur question updated

Comment: Packages are loaded with a `\usepackage` command; in the case at hand, try `\usepackage{url}`.

Comment: @Mico sadly, it doesnt do anything :(

Comment: @jon Sorry but what kind of working example are you referring to ? I have this at the start of my document `% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk` -- Adding that package did not fix the problem.

Comment: Alan Munn's answer shows an example of a minimal working example.  They start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`; and they make everyone's life easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the field "howpublished" is not being recognised as a URL, so any of the methods that people have given to break the URL are not working.  Load the `url` package and change your `.bib` item appropriately so that the `\url` is encoded in the `.bib` file as such:

```
@misc{marsrover,
    Author = {Greicius, Tony},
    Booktitle = {NASA},
    Howpublished = {\url{http://www.nasa.gov/mission\_pages/msl/index.html}},
    Title = {{\{NASA\} - Mars Science Laboratory}},
    Url = {http://www.nasa.gov/mission\_pages/msl/index.html},
    }
```

Minimal document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\cite{marsrover}
\bibliography{library}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Yes this fixed the problem .. it seems like Mendeley does not output webpages correctly .. I might need to ask this in a new topic.

Comment: No, I don't think this is the correct diagnosis.  The issue is what the bibliography style does with the `howpublished` field. This field is a catch-all described in the BibTeX documentation as "How something strange has been published. The first word should be capitalized." So it's not always a URL, so it's up to you to indicate that it *is* a URL when it is one.  This is different from e.g. the `url` field, which (if your bibliography style recognises it) is intended to hold a URL and will be formatted accordingly.

Comment: Hmm I see ... Well is there a way I can automate this rather than manually editing the file every time Mendeley updates the .bib ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about Mendeley. Does it overwrite changes you make to the bib file?

Comment: Yeah, every time I update the reference manager it automatically overwrites any changes done in the bib file.